# cordova background geolocation plugin on reboot

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am building an ionic app with background geolocation plugin `https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation`.

I want to make an app to send its location after reboot. The plugin I am using seems to have the option, but it is not working properly. An app only sends its location to the server only after execute an app at least once after every boot.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

My code is below

**Configuration**

```
backgroundGeolocation.configure(callbackFn, failureFn, {
            locationProvider: backgroundGeolocation.provider.ANDROID_ACTIVITY_PROVIDER,
            desiredAccuracy: 10,
            stationaryRadius: 10,
            distanceFilter: 10,
            interval: 60000,
            maxLocations: 50,
            startOnBoot: true, // from my understanding, this should make an app track its location even after reboot
            stopOnTerminate: false
});
```

**Callback Function**

```
var callbackFn = function(location) {
        console.log('[js] BackgroundGeolocation callback:  ' + location.latitude + ',' + location.longitude);

        // Do your HTTP request here to POST location to your server.
        var link = API_URL;

        $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: link,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
                var str = [];
                for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                return str.join("&");
            },
            params: {
                'device': 'android',
            },
            data: {
                lat:location.latitude,
                lng:location.longitude,
            }
        }).success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });

        backgroundGeolocation.finish();
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope you would have found your answer by now, posting this might help others too.

don't expect your callback to be executed after the reboot, as the activity might be killed, instead use *url* option of the plugin to continue sending your location updates to the server.

Comment: I was able to get the device's location after reboot using option `url`  in configuration. Callback function gets killed after reboot, however, when you post the device's location using configuration option, the device still sends its location to the server. Try to use option `url` in configuration.Check the doc

Comment: How i can use the callback function like watchPosition function i mean i want to get the location of device after specific intervals regularly when app is running in background, i need to draw the polyline.